# The following classes could not be instantiated : android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView

Tags: java, android, android-layout, nullpointerexception

I created a new project on android studio and while I'm running MainActivity I have got a nullPointerException on `setContentView()`, for now, my activity is empty and I haven't written any code and my activity_main.xml contains just a `RelativeLayout`, when I checked the XML preview I saw this error:
**The following classes could not be instantiated: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView** but I don't use AppCompatTextView, I have tried to change the style and change com.android.support:appcompat-v7 version but it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 0):

Add support v7 lib in buid.gradle file, make sure you have got internet when you resolve it.

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0' //or the version you are using
```

Comment: sorry but i'm already using com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0

Comment: Do you mean `build.gradle`?

Answer (score -1):

please try `MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity`
hope it helps

Comment: please provide an explanation